# Consuming messages concurrently with an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run a pretty basic application utilizing RabbitMQ in Java. I'd simple like to consume messages concurrently using a Java `ExecutorService`. My project is using Spring, so I've defined my `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="8"/>   
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="600"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="16"/>
    <property name="threadGroupName" value="CallbackQueue-Group"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="CallbackQueue-Worker-"/>
</bean>
```

I'm injecting this bean into my main mesasge queue utilizing class which is doing something like this:

```
this.connection = getConnectionFactory().newConnection(getQueueExecutor());
this.channel = this.connection.createChannel();
this.channel.queueDeclare(getQueueName(), true, false, false, null);
this.channel.basicConsume(getQueueName(), false, new DefaultConsumer(this.channel) {
    @Override public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, 
            BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Received message {}", properties.getCorrelationId());

        try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {};

        getChannel().basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }
});
```

Simply put, when I post multiple messages to the queue, I should see the log statements happen fairly close together, even though the tasks take a while to execute. However, I'm seeing that my consumer is only processing *one task at a time*, in spite of the `ExecutorService`! What's even weirder is that I'm actually seeing different threads in the pool service the queue, albeit never at the same time:

```
12:43:40.650 [CallbackQueue-Worker-2] DEBUG MyApplication - Received message 65bfbba29b4965eb0674c082c73dad7c
12:43:43.737 [CallbackQueue-Worker-3] DEBUG MyApplication - Received message 2a0b29012b13857c5a0ae8060f66dbaa
12:43:46.755 [CallbackQueue-Worker-3] DEBUG MyApplication - Received message 3c0742f9a284ac9c6b602200254c70db
12:43:49.769 [CallbackQueue-Worker-3] DEBUG MyApplication - Received message a462236fab19d51ba4bfea1582410a64
12:43:52.783 [CallbackQueue-Worker-3] DEBUG MyApplication - Received message 1a4713e1066dfc9e4ec1302098450a1f
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there some additional configuration which I missed in either my `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` or in my RabbitMQ code?

Comment: I know you asked this about 2 years ago. Hope you might recall. I have  to implement similar scenario where I need a pool of worker threads (ExecutorService) to consume messages from Rabbit queue. Any success on this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm currently stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From description of com.rabbitmq.client.Channel:

> While a Channel can be used by multiple threads, it's important to
>   ensure that only one thread executes a command at once. Concurrent
>   execution of commands will likely cause an UnexpectedFrameError to be
>   thrown.

Could this be a reason? Your log shows that different workers are used (we see 2 and 3), but only one worker a time.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be an issue. The entire point of consuming is that it can be done with multiple threads at once so as to be able to make job processing concurrent. Why else would I be able to pass it an `ExecutorService` in the `newConnection` factory method when creating a `Connection`?

Comment: But may be you need to open two or more channels in addition?

Comment: Each channel can serve multiple connections at once, can't it?

Comment: This is marked as the answer, but doesn't really offer a solution. @NaftuliTzviKay, how did this answer help you?

Comment: Instantiate more `Channel`s. If you want 8 threads, create 8 channels and have one thread service each one.

Comment: @NaftuliKay better way would be to post only this as answer and accept it - then one who is looking for solution would not have to read all comments here ;)